# Number of constraints for a 2D (image plane of camera) projection of a line in 3D

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, computer-vision

Suppose there are 'n' lines in 3D. Since each line has 4 Degrees of Freedom (DOF), total DOF as I understand should be $4n$.

> As per [Camera Calibration Using Line Correspondences](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/cvpr93/Qfromlines/Q-from-lines.pdf), Section 2.5: Degree of Freedom

up to projectivity n lines have $4n - 15$ DOF provided  $n \ge 5.^2 $.

I don't quite understand this, can anyone please explain this to me.

Thanks in advance